# Why are cookies not saving in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cookies

This is driving me crazy. In my AppController, I have the following:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Cookie->name = 'MyCookie';
    $this->Cookie->time =  '1 year';
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'http://mydomain.com';
    $firstVisit = $this->Cookie->read('foo');
    if ( empty($firstVisit) ) {
        $this->set('firstVisit', true);
        $this->Cookie->write('foo', 'true');
    } else {
        $this->set('firstVisit', false);
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work, but nothing is returned and the cookie is completely blank.

What could possible be preventing Cake from actually saving the Cookie?

Comment: When you remove the line that saves the cookie it doesn't save the cookie?

Comment: Exactly. When I take out the `write` the cookie is completely blank, which means nothing is actually getting written to the cookie.

Comment: So when you don't write anything to the cookie, nothing is written to the cookie? Is this some kind of joke?

Comment: I try writing to the cookie once. I remove the write portion. My expectation is that I'll be able to READ what was previously written to the cookie, until the cookie expires.

Comment: You need to tell it which cookie to read. `$this->Cookie->read( 'foo' );`

Comment: I edited the question to have more code. I tried doing that. What I'm try to say is that nothing actually gets written to the cookie, at all. I've debugged, and values do not persist.

Answer (score 4):

The cookies are not set until the View is rendered. Maybe you do not have a view for your controller?

Answer (score 2):

The `http://` caused it to break. Removing that fixed the problem.